# How to properly design non-flat menu and tool bar icons in aero style?

Tags: vector, icon, shadows

I'm looking for a comprehensive guide on designing non-flat icons for toolbars and menus in applications like the one you can see in Matlab [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a89gr.png) or Excel 2010 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0YUP.png).

The problem is, that you don't find much icon themes in that style and if you find one, it is very high priced which I can't afford as an open source developer. And most open source themes like Tango (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons) or free-to-use themes like the Silk icons (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Silk_icons) either don't have all the icons I need or don't have icons in a high resolution for High DPI displays.

Therefore I decided to try it on my own. At least I won't have legal issues if I design them on my own. I have some basic knowledge about Inkscape but I really struggle with things like colors, gradients, shadows and '3-dimensionality' / realism. I'm just used to flat icons but I don't like them. Do you have a comprehensive guide or tutorial series which I can follow?

[image: Matlab 2022 ribbon bar]
1: Screenshot of MATLAB R2022b ribbon bar. Source: Self made.

[image: Excel 2010 ribbon bar]
2: Screenshot of Excel 2010 ribbon bar. Source: https://www.maxiorel.com/first-glimpse-ms-office-2010-excel-2010

Comment: https://graphicriver.net/item/1400-user-interface-icons/14298656 https://graphicriver.net/item/user-interface/34781662

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It might be worth your while opening up some of the open source SVGs in Inkscape. Then you can disassemble them and find out exactly how they were actually made. [see example](https://imgur.com/JTGtLQp).

Comment: To be fair though, if you only have a basic knowledge of Inkscape, it might take you some time to acquire the skills needed to make your own.  A good youtube channel for Inkscape is Logos by Nick. The tutorials aren't specifically about icon creation, but everything you learn can be applied to icon design.

Comment: Welcome hefe! *Effective* icon design isn't a simple thing, even for accomplished software users or designers. (which is why *many* icons tend to look the same.) I think this question is a bit broad. It's not only a matter of understanding *why* any icon would be effective. On top of that, it's also a matter of understanding how to use the tools (software) to create icons.